# How to change heap and stack memory size in GCC 4.6.3?

Tags: c, memory, gcc, ubuntu-12.04, heap-memory

While using malloc I have noticed that the pointer assigned is null. I want to allocate much more memory around 30 MB to the heap memory during execution of the code. How can I do so on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with GCC 4.6.3 used as a compiler?  Should I allocate more stack memory instead? Would it be better?

Thanks

Edit the problematic part of the code, the code is terminated after the if statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define a0 0.53 
#define N LONG_MAX
// This value of N is the highest possible number in long double
// data format over 100. Higher is not possible due to the size of 
// the default heap memory. Change its value  to adjust the precision of 
// integration and computation time. Since exponential decays really fast
// a modest value of N is enough for this integration.
// The discrete integral may be defined as follows:
long double trapezoid(long double x[],long double f[]) {
  int i;
  long double dx = x[1]-x[0];
  long double sum = 0.5*(f[0]+f[N]);

    for (i = 1; i <  N; i++) 
        sum+=f[i];
  return sum*dx;  
}
main() {
    printf("LONG_MAX constant has the following value: %ld \n", LONG_MAX);
    long double * P = malloc(N * sizeof(long double));
    long double * r = malloc(N * sizeof(long double));
    long double * PP = malloc(N * sizeof(long double));
    // The if statement is to check if the memory allocation has 
    // been done and terminate the program otherwise.
    if (P == 0 || r == 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    // Declare and initialize the loop variable
}
```

Comment: Heap is the way to go for big chunks of memory. I am able to allocate one gigabyte easily with `malloc`, so your problem is elsewhere. Are you working on a particularly limited platform?

Comment: Is your system configured to limit per process memory allocation? What is the output of `ulimit -v`?

Comment: Are you allocating in one big chunk, or are you making multiple smaller allocations? How many?

Comment: You should show a [self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/) of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @MagnusHoff ulimit's output is unlimited and I am working from the virtual terminal. I am allocating in one big chunk.

Comment: Dude! You are trying to allocate `LONG_MAX * sizeof(long double)` bytes. This is `9223372036854775807 * 16 = 147573952589676412912` bytes on my machine, which is something like 128 exabytes. I'm guessing you don't have enough RAM.

Comment: LONG_MAX * sizeof(double) is, uh, way bigger than 30MB.

Comment: ..which the OP would have noticed if it had read the malloc size into an intermediate auto, turned off optimization and used a debugger to single-step and check the values.  Can nobody debug anymore?

Comment: I miscalculated it at first.Having the size of the long double printed to be 12 bytes then 12 * 2147483647 = 24576 MB. I think that is the problem being much larger than the typical size of RAM.

Comment: On a 64-bit system (which most desktop Linux installs are nowadays), `LONG_MAX` is something like 2**16 times larger than the total amount of mappable address space; *even if* you happened to have that much RAM (and I'm not sure a computer with that much RAM has ever been built), you couldn't allocate it all to the same process!

Comment: ... and if `LONG_MAX` is only 2147483647, then you're *still* trying to allocate more memory than will fit in your virtual address space (or else you're on 64-bit Windows, with its deranged "SIZE_MAX < ULONG_MAX" ABI, and you have bigger problems).

Comment: I was running 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS since I was concerned about driver compatibility at the time of installation.

Comment: OK, on a 32-bit system you usually have a hard upper limit of 2 or 3 (binary) gigabytes of address space per user-space process -- and that's for *everything*, code, data, stack, and miscellaneous; there may not be enough *contiguous* addresses to satisfy even a 1G `malloc`, even if there is enough RAM and swap to back it.